# How are local edits of packaged Lighting flexi-pages handled when a package is updated?

Tags: managed-package, flexipages, push-upgrade, lightning-page

I read in this [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.packaging_packageable_components.htm&type=5) that Lightning pages (AKA flexi-pages) are upgradeable. But these pages are also locally editable.

So how does this work? Do local edits always win, or does the latest update replace the local edit? Or something better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lightning Pages aren't really subscriber-editable. It's a mirage.

When the subscriber performs what really does look, in the UI, like an edit to a packaged FlexiPage, they're actually cloning the component and will save it under a different API name. This quiet clone preserves the expected invariants of packaging:

1. The user's edits are undisturbed through upgrades, because they're not in a packaged component.
2. The vendor can deliver upgrades to the packaged component, which the subscriber can choose to incorporate (or not) into their local clone.

Comment: Very helpful David and makes sense. Two clarifications: 1) I assume this means that if the customer does **not** edit, they will automatically see the new flexi-page supplied in an upgrade; 2) Is the process of the subscriber incorporating changes into their local clone completely manual and based on separate documentation (i.e. the packaged upgrade version isn't visible).

Comment: Yes and yes. Subject, of course, to how the subscriber is currently consuming the packaged and cloned pages; it's perfectly possible for them to be using both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for all this David!